# How to change state of a flow using groovy script in mule 4?

Tags: groovy, mulesoft, mule4

I have two flows, Flow 1 and Flow 2.

Flow 1

- http listener - receive the request from external system.
- groovy script ( change the initial state of the flow 2 )

flow 2

- Jms on new message , read new message from queue.
- http request to call system api.

Question : flow 1 step 2 - groovy script can this is possible ?

Comment: Hi @AlkeshGaijar. Are you asking how to start or stop a flow programmatically?

Comment: Note that you can not change the initial state of a flow. You may change the current state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible as explained in this article: [How To Stop Or Start Flows In Mule 4.x Programmatically](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-To-Stop-Or-Start-Flows-In-Mule-4-x-Programmatically)

> You will need to perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Add the scripting module to your project if you haven't previously added it.
> 2. Add a scripting with a script similar to below:
>
> ```xml
> <scripting:execute engine="groovy" doc:name="Toggle flow">
>     <scripting:code>
>       flow = registry.lookupByName(&quot;flowName&quot;).get();
>       if (flow.isStarted())
>         flow.stop()
>       else 
>         flow.start()
>     </scripting:code> 
> </scripting:execute>
> ```
>
> That Script will start the flow with name "flowName" if it is not
> started and stop it otherwise. Please replace "flowName" with the
> actual name of the flow you wish to start/stop or with a variable.